# Trying to return an image REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

My code will not work for this REST API function

```
@PostMapping(value = "/image", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<BufferedImage> getImage() {
    
    
    BufferedImage img = null;

    try{
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("/static/images/agents/1.jpg"));
    }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return successResponse(img);
}
```

I am getting the exception "javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!". This is the location of the file in my spring boot project, how can I fix this?

Comment: The file location could be wrong. Find the absolute path and construct it accordingly.

Comment: I dont think the file location is wrong

Comment: Do you have a directory starting from your root like this `/static/images/agents`? Or do you have a folder relative to some other base directory?

Comment: Try to remove `/` from the begining `/static...`. And check again. By starting your path with `/` means absolute path.

Comment: Please read https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file

Comment: In my Netbeans Project underneath "Other Sources" I have src/main/resouces as standard. Then static.images.agents

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have used Simon Martinellis link to fix the error